Existence of square free factorisation.
A polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_q[x]$ is said to be square-free if it has no repeated roots.
The square-free factorisation of $f$ is
$$f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k f_i(x)^i,$$ where each $f_i(x)$ is square free polynomial and $\gcd(f_i(x), f_j(x))$ is $1$ for $i\neq j$.
My basic doubt is why exponent $i$ is appearing in the factorisation? Why can't we then say that $f_2(x)^2$ divides $f(x)$ (suppose it is not $1$), which means $f$ is not square free.

That looks like a typo.

If it were some other symbol, let's say $\epsilon_i$, then it could make sense each exponent were restricted to $\epsilon_i = 0$ or $\epsilon_i = 1$ for each $i$. This can be useful when comparing two or more factorizations, since we might like to name any factor that appears in any of the polynomials.

But same symbol is used at other references also (e.g. on wikipedia).

Oh! You're right. The factors $f_i$ are square-free, not the product $f$, in the definition given there of a square-free factorization.

Oh, I'm wrong (and have deleted my incorrect comment).  You aren't requiring that the $f_i$ be irreducible, so the expression makes sense.   You can just gather together all the factors that have the same exponents.  here is a reference.

If you read the definition closely, it's a statement about factoring an arbitrary polynomial in a particular way involving increasing powers of square-free polynomials. The factors are square-free.
This is just a statement about sorting. Basically, $f_1$ is a product of irreducible factors that only appear once, $f_2^2$ is a product of irreducible factors that appear exactly twice, etc.
There's even an efficient algorithm due to Yun to construct these factors.
